# Flash AS3 still image followed with animated stuff

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm stuck in how to make my still image come out together with the animated stuff.
When i click the button 1, the image 1 appears from the right side, i want to make my still image followed with the animated bear to give short instruction about the images. And then when i click button 2, all of the images and animated things gone, then come out the image 2 and followed with another animated stuff. I hope somebody could help me in this.

Thank you.

Comment: You're going to give us some code examples here. There could be a million and one things wrong with your logic based on what you have provided. We need you to narrow it down a bit for us.

Answer (score 0):

Put in separated movieclips, movieclips has their own timeline them you can bring it like another image file because they have similar properties.